# How to pass a JSON parameter to RESTful WCF service?

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest

I develloped a Restful WCF service, and I need to pass a json string as an input. The json string is variable.
This is my service:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "{id}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
public string GetById(string id)
{

    string sampleItem = id;


    return sampleItem;
}
```

And this is a json example:

```
{  
   "name":"obj1",
   "x":11,
   "y":20,
   "obj":{  
      "testKey":"val"
   },
   "z":30,
   "tab":[  
      1,
      2,
      46
   ],
   "employees":[  
      {  
         "firstName":"John",
         "lastName":"Doe"
      },
      {  
         "firstName":"Anna",
         "lastName":"Smith"
      },
      {  
         "firstName":"Peter",
         "lastName":"Jones"
      }
   ]
}
```

when http://localhost:7626/Service1/myjsonstring

I get this error: Erreur HTTP 400 - Bad Request.

P.S: if I pass a simple string it works.
Any ideas plz

Comment: First of all your JSON is invalid `obj` should be wrapped with `"`. The second thing, do you really want to receive JSON as string? Maybe you want to get a deserialized model, which WCF can do without any problem?

Comment: I want to pass it in input as a string.

Comment: Where are you calling this service from?

Comment: I'm not developping the app that consume the service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I suggest that you need to use POST method for such purposes. The easiest way to read the raw string is get it as a `Stream`. So your service interface might look like that:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "PostJson")]
    string PostJson(Stream request);
}
```

And implementation:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string PostJson(Stream request)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(request))
        {
            return "You posted: " + reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Please also check that you have correct configuration in your Web.Config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
      <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior" 
                binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
                contract="WcfService1.IService1">
      </endpoint>
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="restfulBehavior">
        <webHttp />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but there is still a problem with the Web.Config, I think

Comment: I get this when debbugging: "fail to add service. service's metadara are not accessible. Check that your service is running and expose metadata"

Comment: I edited the answer and now you can see the full `system.serviceModel` section from my config. You can also check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/571813/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Creating-WCF-REST-Services) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-By-Step-Guide) articles. Both articles has details of how to make web.configs for restful WCF correctly.

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem, But now I can't still test the operation "PostJson".. "This operation is not supported by WCF test client because it uses System.IO.Stream"

Comment: Yes, streams are not supported by WCF Test Client. But because you are doing HTTP stuff, you can use some other test cleint. My favorite is [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), it's free and popular, so it's not a problem to find tutorials.